# Preciso administrar um campo text com valores separadas ;

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso inserir, editar, apagar um campo do tipo text nesse formato:

```
11 2222-3333;11 3333-4444;11 5555-6666;11 7777-8888
```

No caso preciso de uma grid zebrada que liste os dados e em cada linha tenha essas informações nesse formato:

Inserir

```
telefone            acoes
11 2222-3333   editar | apagar
11 3333-4444   editar | apagar
11 5555-6666   editar | apagar
11 7777-8888   editar | apagar
```

Porem apos a inserção, edição ou deletar que continue a manter o formato no campo text do *MySQL*.

Comment: A pergunta parece muito com "Escrevam o código pra mim a partir do zero (e grátis)". A resposta do Zero Cool parece bem apropriada: simplesmente uma indicação genérica (pra uma pergunta genérica).

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro usar as tabelas zebradas do Bootstrap e um plugin do jQuery chamado Mask

- Tabelas Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#tables
- Plugin Mask: http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/1.6.4/

Comment: Para quebrar a string inicial use o explode como Harry Potter respondeu adicionando uma string com link dentro do echo no foreach

Comment: tem algum exemplo disso funcionando